# -5V to 5V DAC Design

Tags: signal-processing, dac

I am trying to design a 10 bit DAC using an R-2R ladder. I hope to achieve a signal that can vary from -5V to 5V.

In the circuit provided, I am showing my design for 5 inputs. I have used Mosfets instead of directly connecting the MCU I/O pins to the DAC because their resistance varies a lot with the temp.

My question is, does this seem like a viable circuit in terms of generating the desired output signal.

This is my first time on this site so if I violated any of the posting rules, I apologize.

Thank you for your time!
[image: DAC circuit design]

*Update: I have adjusted the requirement of the DAC to produce a 0 to 1V signal which I will adjust using an opamp.

Based on the replies, I believe this circuit should do the trick!
[image: Updated Circuit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Won't work. You need to drive the ends of the 2R resistors push-pull from +5 to -5, not just to +5, so you need something like complementary MOSFETs and level shifters.

---

Edit after 2nd schematic added- since Vdd is 3.3V you need a more complex level shifter. Maybe something like this:

R2/Q2 could be replaced with a logic level MOSFET- 2N7000 is a bit marginal at 3.3V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fke2OM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Unless you are doing this for educational purposes it may be better to just buy a DAC. Of course you could also use a high-Z R2R ladder off the MCU and use an op-amp to shift the 0-3.3V output to +/-5V. Plenty of answers here on that sort of thing.

Comment: I figure my I/O pins would also need to swing from -5 to 5 volts to make a complementary switching circuit work.

Comment: Yes, hence the level shifter I mentioned. For example a p-channel MOSFET + resistor per output.